# linking CSS into django .html file

Tags: django

I am really lost in finding out how to link to an external .css file in my html template. I have read (or at least tried to read) this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ and am still lost. My .html file is in

```
C:\Users\me\Documents\mysite\templates
```

and my .css file is in

```
C:\Users\me\Documents\mysite\templates\static\css
```

In settings.py, I made

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/me/Documents/mysite/templates/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In my .html file, I am trying to link the CSS by doing

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

any idea what I am missing or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The ``static` folder must be out of the `templates` folder.

Comment: hm, still doesn't work.. I tried putting the static folder after mysite, and changing STATIC_ROOT to 'C:/Users/me/Documents/mysite/static' and then changing the href to {{ STATIC_URL }}/templates/css/style.css

Comment: `static` folder must be into  `myapp` folder at the same level than `templates` folder and `views.py`

Comment: I'll put it as answer

Answer (score 0):

`static` folder must be into `myapp` folder at the same level than `templates` folder and `views.py`